I am trying to use flutter_timezone but it give me the error when i run the application
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':flutter_timezone'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':flutter_timezone:classpath'.
   > Could not download gradle-4.2.2.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2)
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.2.2/gradle-4.2.2.jar'.      
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.2.2/gradle-4.2.2.jar'.
            > The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used. See: https://docs.gradle.org/7.6.3/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
               > Remote host terminated the handshake
   > Could not download kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.6.21.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.21)
      > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.6.21/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.6.21.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.6.21/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.6.21.jar'.
            > No such host is known (repo.maven.apache.org)
   > Could not download builder-4.2.2.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:4.2.2)
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/4.2.2/builder-4.2.2.jar'.    
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/4.2.2/builder-4.2.2.jar'.
            > No such host is known (dl.google.com)
   > Could not download protos-27.2.2.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:protos:27.2.2)
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/protos/27.2.2/protos-27.2.2.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/protos/27.2.2/protos-27.2.2.jar'.
            > dl.google.com
   > Could not download guava-29.0-jre.jar (com.google.guava:guava:29.0-jre)
      > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/29.0-jre/guava-29.0-jre.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/29.0-jre/guava-29.0-jre.jar'.
            > repo.maven.apache.org
   > Could not download kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.6.21.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:1.6.21)
      > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-compiler-embeddable/1.6.21/kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.6.21.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-compiler-embeddable/1.6.21/kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.6.21.jar'.
            > repo.maven.apache.org
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':flutter_timezone' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
   > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':flutter_timezone' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4m 35s

i was trying to use flutter_timezone in my project but it give me this error when i run the command flutter run  and it return this error, it return me some build.gradle error in the terminal, i have try so many times to make changes in the build.gradle file but nothing is working the issue is the same for the every time.
the build.gradle file contains this code -
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "com.example.guidechef"
    compileSdk flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.guidechef"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {}


Looks like network issue. please rebuild again and let me know if this issue persist.
